# turtle graphics(python): NameError: name '_name_' is not defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, turtle-graphics

Recently I was using an online free IDE -- Repl.it and in which, I got stuck with the following error ! NameError: name '*name*' is not defined on line 16. Thanks for guidance and wonderful support in advance. How can I trouble shoot this error?

```
import turtle
def draw_bag():
 turtle.shape('turtle')
 turtle.pencolor('brown')
 turtle.pensize(5)
 turtle.penup()
 turtle.goto(-35, 35)
 turtle.pendown()
 turtle.right(90)
 turtle.forward(70)
 turtle.left(90)
 turtle.forward(70)
 turtle.left(90)
 turtle.forward(70)

if _name_=='_main_':
  turtle.setworldcoordinates(-70., -70., 70., 70.)
  draw_bag()
  turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is double underscore not single. 
`if __name__ == '__main__'`.